FlutterFlow Firebase Push Notification doesn't match mobile device's notification style
I flutterflow app I have connected firebase database. And then enabled push notification. The notification arrives to my android device, but the notification only shows in my top bar. It doesn't show with popup style like other app's notification.
I expect the notification to show like other notifications.
